# How to inject properties to constructed object?

Tags: c#, dependencies, unity-container, castle-windsor, code-injection

I have a constructed object, and I want to inject properties by name and value.
is there any way to do it using Unity/Castle windsor/ another framework?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it just using .NET:

```
var myObject = new MyObject();

// do something

var fields = typeof(MyObject).GetFields();
foreach (var field in fields) {
    // this is the name of the field itself
    var name = field.Name;

    // this is the current value of the field
    var val = field.GetValue(myObject );

    // this sets the current field to the newValue
    var newValue = 0;
    field.SetValue(myObject, newValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example with unity

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/akkiraju/dependency-injection-techniques-explained-using-structurem/

```
 IUnityContainer unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
 unityContainer.RegisterType<IClassB, ClassB>();
```

using spring

http://springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/quickstarts.html

```
 <object name="AnotherMovieFinder"
     type="Spring.Examples.MovieFinder.ColonDelimitedMovieFinder,  Spring.Examples.MovieFinder">
     <constructor-arg index="0" value="movies.txt"/>
 </object>
```

or with reflection you can implement take the value from any place